# How to create custom iOS View

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview

[image]

I'm looking to create a custom `UIView` (like the above realtor.com app) so when the user selects send email or something to that effect a little view pops up confirming the action then disappears. Any direction, tutorials or code snippets would be greatly appreciated. Also what is the correct terminology of what I'm looking to do? Please excuse my ignorance on this subject.

Comment: There are lots of open-source controls that do this for you already. This would be a good place to start. http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=toast

Comment: to github to search "MBProgressHud"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Custom `UIActivityIndicator` that you can found in this link

https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

This is not Apple specific controls. You can create them. The pop up shown in first image is very easy to make. You'll have to use 3 controls to make it.

1) Background `UIImageView` with the image.

2) UIActivityIndicatory

3) `UILabel` with whatever message you want to display.

`MBProgressHUD` is an iOS drop-in class that displays a translucent HUD with an indicator and/or labels while work is being done in a background thread. The HUD is meant as a replacement for the undocumented, private UIKit UIProgressHUD with some additional features.......
**There is more option that useful for your work, For mor information go to above Link**

Comment: I ended up going this route. Thanks for the input everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use something that's already available?  Take a look at ZAActivityBar (https://github.com/zacaltman/ZAActivityBar) which handles creating 'toast'-like popups.

It's a part of CocoaPods, so it's very easy to install.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can customize,go throgh below steps

1)add selector to your sendEmail button

2)in that selector function create one view, and add your emailSent image as a background

3)now add this view to mainView simply by addSubView

or for nice than above

1)add selector to your sendEmail button

2)in that selector function create one UIControl of size 480 x320, and add a imageView to it & if you want also can add one ok button

3)now add selector for UIControl, in that selector function just remove your view from sperView

4)now add UIcontrol to mainView

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the source code for showing toast like android

https://github.com/scalessec/Toast